# How to apply css to input with ID?

Tags: css

I'm using SurveyProject for my poll and have the question with 2 answers with this html structure:

1 answer:

```
<tr class="answerStyle">
<td class="cellValign">
<span id="SurveyControl_Question18__as50577__ai72_as50577"><div>
<div id="grbD">
<input name="SurveyControl$Question18_as50577:_grp18" class="globalRadioButton" id="SurveyControl_Question18__as50577__ai72_as50577_ctl00" type="radio" value="SurveyControl$Question18$_as50577$_ai72_as50577$ctl00">
<label class="globalRadioButtonLabel" runat="server" associatedcontrolid="SurveyControl_Question18__as50577__ai72_as50577_ctl00">NO</label>    
</div>
</div>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

2 answer:

```
<tr class="answerStyle">
    <td class="cellValign">
        <span id="SurveyControl_Question18__as50577__ai71_as50577">
            <div>
                <div id="grbD">
                    <input name="SurveyControl$Question18_as50577:_grp18" class="globalRadioButton" id="SurveyControl_Question18__as50577__ai71_as50577_ctl00" type="radio" value="SurveyControl$Question18$_as50577$_ai71_as50577$ctl00">
                    <label class="globalRadioButtonLabel" runat="server" associatedcontrolid="SurveyControl_Question18__as50577__ai71_as50577_ctl00">yes<br>comment:</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

As I can't change html, I want to apply style with css for second answer's input with id #SurveyControl_Question18__as50577__ai71_as50577_ctl00, but everything that I tried doesn't work...
I tried:

```
input[name="SurveyControl$Question18_as50577:_grp18"] {
float: left;
margin-top: 20px;
}

#SurveyControl_Question18__as50577__ai71_as50577_ctl00 {
float: left;
margin-top: 20px;
}

#SurveyControl_Question18__as50577__ai71_as50577 input {
float: left;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

And some others, but the only thing which works is:

```
#grbD input {
float: left;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

But this also affects the first answer's input as it uses the same div's id.
Any ideas?

Comment: `#SurveyControl_Question18__as50577__ai71_as50577_ctl00 { your: style }`  will work...

Comment: no, it doesn't... I wrote, that I already tried this one.

Comment: Have you tried overriding any existing styles using `!important`...? You may find that existing styles are far more specific that just an ID...

Comment: No, it's not the case here, thank you though. @lazyHead answer did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using these selectors.

```
.answerStyle:nth-child(2) #grbD input {
float: left;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Or

```
.answerStyle:not(:first-child) #grbD input {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: ".answerStyle:nth-child(2) #grbD input" worked, ".answerStyle:not(:first-child) #grbD input" affected the first one answer anyway. Thank you.

Comment: The second css selector should work. It worked on my use case.. Are you using an older browser?

Comment: I'm using Internet Explorer 11